# getting the location of a static marker when the map is scrolled

Tags: android, dictionary, map-projections

I am trying to create an app where there is a static marker(ImageView) in the map.Initially using the Projection class the the latitude and longitude were 0.0 because the marker was placed in the center of the map in xml. When the user scrolls to a place in map to make it appear below the static marker I want to get the Latitude and longitude of that place, just like uber, ola etc..

map.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        map:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        map:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/marker"
            android:background="@drawable/gps"
            map:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        map:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.035">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edttxt_bg"
            map:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            map:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            map:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.035" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MapActivity.java:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    ImageView marker;
    Projection projection;
    float x,y;int outlocation[];LatLng location;
    Point point;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        marker=findViewById(R.id.marker);
        outlocation=new int[2];

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        projection=mMap.getProjection();
        marker.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                marker.getLocationOnScreen(outlocation);
                Log.e("MarkerX",Integer.toString(outlocation[0]));
                Log.e("MarkerY",Integer.toString(outlocation[1]));
                location=projection.fromScreenLocation(new Point(outlocation[0],outlocation[1]));
                Log.e("Lat",Double.toString(location.latitude));
                Log.e("Longt",Double.toString(location.longitude));
            }
        });
        mMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraMove() {
                marker.getLocationOnScreen(outlocation);
                Log.e("MarkerX",Integer.toString(outlocation[0]));
                Log.e("MarkerY",Integer.toString(outlocation[1]));
                location=projection.fromScreenLocation(new Point(outlocation[0],outlocation[1]));


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You xml looks good, but to solve your problem you could add the OnCameraIdleListener to your map more or less like this:

```
mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(object : GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
    fun onCameraIdle() {
        val position = mMap.getCameraPosition().target
    }
})
```

Google Map.getCameraPosition ().**target** is the center of the map, so you can keep your static imageView on the map that simulates being a marker to allow the user to move the map at will

Greetings

Comment: Yes my friend...I just got it too..mMap.getCameraPosition();.Is this also correct?

Comment: Yes it's, your mMap variable is equals to my mGoogleMap, somthing like this mMap.getCameraPosition().target